# Cannot use passport-facebook-token in Nodejs (object is not a function)!

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm trying to implement an api for my android app which uses FB for authentication. I'm trying to use passport-facebook-token but I get this error when I make a new FacebookTokenStrategy:

> passport.use('facebook-token', ^new FacebookTokenStrategy({ TypeError: object is not a function

here is my code:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var FacebookTokenStrategy= require('passport-facebook-token');
passport.use('facebook-token',new FacebookTokenStrategy({
clientID: "xxxxxxxxxx",
clientSecret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
users.findOrCreate({ facebookId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
return done(err, user);
});
}
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change:

```
require('passport-facebook-token')
```

to:

```
require('passport-facebook-token').Strategy
```

Comment: You are awesome bro.. But what is the way to find it out.. by checking module code?